# Using Mono on DOS

Tags: .net, mono, dos

I want to run .NET applications on DOS and I was thinking of using the Mono Framework, but DOS does not appear to be a supported platform.  Is there a way to use Mono or the MS.NET Framework on DOS?

Comment: Really? Which version of DOS?

Comment: DOS? Serious? As in, Disk Operating System?

Comment: I am sooooo starring this. I really want to watch the discussion unfold.

Comment: I'm using MSDOS from Windows 98, but I'm thinking of using MSDOS 7.1 instead.

Comment: I'd start with trying to build Mono with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DJGPP - sure, some limited porting work would be required.

Comment: .NET version 2 is supposedly [supported for Windows 98](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=19).

Comment: @Dr. Wily's Apprentice:  I've already tried using .net 2.0 after booting into DOS and it doesn't work.  I have also tried to run .net apps using a DPMI extender, but I have to copy all of the .net librarys to the application folder, which is hard.

Comment: You also can't use SQL Server on an Apple II-E, if you want to try something equally silly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty sure that pretty much **nothing** is supported on DOS these days. If you want a console-based platform that will work on a low-power machine, then there are plenty of flavours of linux  that would do fine here, and work with Mono.

If you just mean "from the command line", then MS .NET will work fine invoked from the console in Windows.

Comment: What Linux distros would you suggest that boot to a command line and use under 128 Mb of RAM?

Comment: @StackUnderflow you could try asking on linux.SE, but: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-distributions-5/suitable-distribution-for-my-low-memory-128-mb-pc-463275/

Comment: @StackUnderflow almost all of them :). Look at "Damn Small Linux". Even a bare debian install will work very well on limited RAM.  Mono won't do that well in 128mb though..

Comment: When I try to install the Compact Framework, it tells me that MS Document Explorer is not installed, but I can't find an installer for it.

Comment: @StackUnderflow a few unconfirmed options bottom of: http://forums.asp.net/t/1403241.aspx/1

Comment: Angstrom + Mono worked fine for me on some ARM SoC. http://www.angstrom-distribution.org/

Answer (score 0):

If yer just looking for a "command line" environment to run your app from, and don't actually need DOS itsself... then try the [COSMOS](http://cosmos.codeplex.com/) project

Comment: I have actually already been using Cosmos, but if you know how to start an app from it, that would be great.

Comment: I do not... I've only used COSMOS for 15 min or so as an expirement.  Have you tried Process.Start() or perhaps something from the System.Reflection namespace?

Comment: I don't think it's supported.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have ime to do the research right now.  I'll check back in a couple days and if you haven't found a good answer I'll see what I can find.