# Running a C# console application in dos?

Tags: c#, dos

I recently got an old dos/windows 3.1 laptop. I'd like to know if it'd be possible to run my console applications made in c# in it.

I'm aware that this is possibly a very stupid question, but I was really wondering if it would be possible.

If it's not, what is the best option for someone with the very basic knowlegde of c# to write some little programs for dos or windows 3.1?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have only very basic knowledge of C# then it doesn't matter. Just learn to write programs for DOS in whatever language is available.

Comment: I actually like your question. Someone had to ask it eventually. :D

Comment: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/net-everywhere-apparently-also-means-windows-311-and-dos
Check this out

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I recently got an old dos/windows 3.1 laptop. I'd like to know if it'd be possible to run my console applications made in c# in it.

No.

Windows 3.1 shipped in 1992 and is a 16 bit operating system. C# 1.0 shipped in 2002, ten years later, and requires a 32 bit operating system.

> If it's not, what is the best option for someone with the very basic knowlegde of c# to write some little programs for dos or windows 3.1?

Learn Basic instead. Several versions of Basic are available for Windows 3.1.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll look into vb instead then.

Comment: GWBasic or BasicA should already be included with DOS

Comment: Might be a little late, but apparently this guy managed to compile, link and run a simple C# application in Windows 3.11 and MSDOS: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/NETEverywhereApparentlyAlsoMeansWindows311AndDOS.aspx. It is a nice experiment, however sacrifices were made and in the end i second Eric Lipper when he says to learn Basic (or C) when writing some programs for DOS.

Answer (score 5):

No. DOS does not support the .NET framework, or should I say the .NET Framework doesn't support DOS...

Answer (score 2):

Even [.net 1.1 is only supported as far back as windows 98](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z6watww%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

Your best bet would probably be reformatting your old laptop, installing a [lightweight linux distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Linux_distribution) and try your programs on [mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page).

Answer (score 1):

No. You need to be able to run the .NET runtimes for C#, which probably won't let you go earlier than Windows XP.  DOS/Windows 3.1 is not supported for .NET. You could use an older VB, maybe but it won't be .NET.

Comment: .NET 1 did do 98 for a while, if I recall.

Answer (score 1):

This question has been asked before on Stack Overflow:
[Using Mono on DOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8670325/using-mono-on-dos)

Since C# is an open standard, there have been other implementations of C# other than the Microsoft one.   One popular one is mono.

You may want to consider loading Linux up on that laptop of yours.  You'd get more capability out of it under Linux than you would out of DOS/Win31.

Answer (score 1):

So everyone else has already answered that .NET won't work for you with your current configuration, as an alternative I'll suggest that you'll be much better off installing some variation of Linux and using Mono...

Comment: Thanks! I was already planning on installing Linux on my system. This will most likely speed things up a little :)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do c#, you'll need the .NET framework. as far as I know there is no .net framework for such old systems...

Answer (score 0):

.NET does not run on DOS. There is an open source project called FreeDOS, but it does not appear to run .NET programs. From [FreeDOS' page](http://www.freedos.org/):

> FreeDOS is a complete, free, DOS-compatible operating system. While we
>   provide our own programs and utilities, you should be able to run any
>   program that was intended for MS-DOS. You can even do networking!
>   However, you may experience problems running Windows on FreeDOS. For
>   example, Windows standard-mode works on FreeDOS, but 386-mode Windows
>   for Workgroups 3.11 does not.